# Owl carousel doesn't work

Tags: 7, javascript

I can't understand how to install Owl Carousel module for Drupal 7.

I installed module from here - https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel
And downloaded additional files from here - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Put this folder in "sites/all/libraries" and managed fields for my content type. I can see few images on my page, but carousel doesn't work.

Here is the error from chrome console - "Uncaught TypeError: o.owlCarousel is not a function"
"GET https://mysite/owl.carousel.min.js?p44xlt net::ERR_ABORTED"

Answer (score 1):

Bit old, but for module version 1, you have to use OwlCarousel 1
https://github.com/InchoonPark/meteor-owl-carousel-1/

Answer (score -1):

Please check that you have installed [jquery_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module.

Comment: Of Course. It's installed and enabled. I believe, that I can't enable Owl Carousel, if I don't have all needed modules enabled

Comment: Have you checked the version of the jquery for front end should be greater then 1.9.

Comment: Yeah it's greater than 1.9
I have found that carousel js trying to includes like this - "<script type="text/javascript" src="/owl.carousel.min.js?p44z30"></script>"
Instead of "site/all/libraries/owlcarousel/dist/...". How can I fix that?

Comment: You have to enable Library module.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/5mdqoxWfvWyMN2

Comment: also cross check the library folder name should be "owl-carousel" and place all css and js in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73124/discussion-between-chandraveer-and-nikita-yunoshev).